# Study $ h(x)= \sqrt{x^2-1}-x-3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let $g$ be the function defined by
>     $$\begin{array}{lrcl}
>  h : & [1;+\infty[  & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
>      & x & \longmapsto & h(x)= \sqrt{x^2-1}-x-3 \end{array}$$
>
> - Study the Variations on $[1;+\infty [$, of function $g$
> - Deduce the sign of $g$ according to $x$

**My proof:**

we have $h'(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1} }-1$, always positive on the interval$[1; +\infty[$ , then $h$ is strictly increasing ($ h'$ isn't vanishes for any number $\forall x \in[1;+\infty[,\quad  h'(x)\neq 0$) on the same interval, since it is continuous, it has $h( [1;+\infty[)=[h(1) ;\lim_{x\to +\infty}h(x)[=[-4;-3[$

and then  $h$ is negative on the interval $[1 ;+\infty[$

- Is My proof correct ? is there any other way to prove it. Thanks.

Update:
here how i calculate the $\lim_{x\to +\infty}h(x)=-3$

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(x)&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x^2-1}-x-3\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{(\sqrt{x^2-1}-(x+3))(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x+3)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}+(x+3)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{((x^2-1)-(x+3)^2)}{x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+(x+3)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{-6-\frac{10}{x}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1+\frac{3}{x}}=\frac{-6}{2}=-3
\end{align}

Comment: Be careful in the way you write your proof -- $g$ is not differentiable at $1$,only on $(1,\infty)$ (also, why did $h$ become $g$?). You also may want to expand a bit on why $\lim_\infty g = -3$.

Comment: @Educ Another interesting feature of this function is asymptotic behavior. When examining the function, I think this is also important.

Comment: @ClementC. it's just typo i'll fix it ok i will elaborate the limit

Comment: @imranfat yes it's quit intersting

Comment: @Educ Do you think there is a slant asymptote for $x$ to negative infinity?